# switching and then fading an image simultaneously

Tags: jquery, html, fading

When a user clicks on a small thumbnail image I then want a larger div element on the same page to then display that image. So far that works with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img#thumb").click(function () {              //when image with ID thumb is clicked change src 
    var imgpath = $(this).attr("src");
    $("img#cover").attr("src", imgpath);
});

});
```

However I now want the old image to fade out while simultaneously switching the new one depending on whichever thumbnail the user clicks. I track the thumb clicked by making jQuery save the src file to a variable then put that in a new path using `.attr()`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure i catched what you need but this should be ok, try :

```
  $(function(){
        $("img#thumb").bind('click',function () {               
        var img = $(this).clone(); //this clones the img, so you do not need to re-load that using src path
        $(this).fadeOut(500);
        $("img#cover").hide().html(img).fadeIn(500); //remove .hide() segment if you just are hiding by css rules

        });

        });
```

Comment: Thank you was very helpful. Once a thumb is clicked I want the image that already there to switch instantly "behind" the new one and the now 'old' image to fade out.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean to fade out the cover image.

If that you can try:

```
$("img#cover").fadeOut();
$("img#cover").attr("src", imgpath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be rather [**on**](http://api.jquery.com/on) event rather than [**click**](http://api.jquery.com/click) event of jquery. You could even leverage [**live**](http://api.jquery.com/live) but that's now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my interpretation of what you are trying to accomplish: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2MPfa/7/).

**HTML**

```
<img class="thumb" src="/img/logo.png" width="100" />
<img class="thumb" src="http://www.wpclipart.com/sign_language/thumbs_up_large.png" width="100" />

<div class="cover">
    <img id="cover" width="400"/>
    <img id="cover-old" width="400"/>
</div>
​
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $("img.thumb").on('click', function() { //when image with ID thumb is clicked change src 
        var imgpath = $(this).attr("src");
        $("#cover-old").attr('src', $("#cover").attr('src'));
        $("#cover-old").show();
        $("#cover").hide();
        $("#cover").attr("src", imgpath);
        $("#cover-old").fadeOut('slow');
        $("#cover").fadeIn('slow');
    });
});​
```

**CSS**

```
.cover {
    position: relative;

}
.cover img {
    position: absolute;
}
​
```

Comment: all of your scripts makes re-loading the image, if is the same path which is the reason why you re-load that?

Comment: If that's a problem you could just verify that the `src` attribute is different before doing the replacement.

Comment: I am making a gallery so there will be 5 thumbnail div elements so as a user clicks on a thumb the gallery 'enlarges' the image in the main viewfinder.

Comment: yes thanks this is exactly the idea that I was trying to describe. much appreciated!